# NuGet Package Manager not working in Visual Studio 2017 - for a.NET Core 1.1 web application

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget-package-restore, asp.net-core-1.1, .net-core-1.1

I just created a .NET Core Web Application in VS2017 and I wanted to be able to serve a single page application. In order to be able to do that I tried to install the nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles. But my NuGet installer failed and threw the following error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>     Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'MyApp'.

Comment: Your question is too broad and does not offer enough information for someone to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the `project=>Properties` and set `TargetFramework` to `.net core 2.0`(less than or equal to the packages version you are using)

build the project and then install whatever you want from `nuget`.